# std::dynamic_pointer_cast isn't casting correctly downwards

Tags: c++, templates, stl, casting, smart-pointers

I'm having an issue that I'll explain after I post the code:

```
template <class T> 
std::shared_ptr<T>
getWidget(const std::string& id) {
  auto iter = findObject(id);

  if (iter != m_widgets.end()) return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(*iter);

  return nullptr;
}

const Widget::Ptr
getType(const std::string& id) {
  auto iter = findObject(id);

  if (iter != m_widgets.end()) {
    if ((*iter)->getWidgetType() == "Label")
      return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Label>(*iter);
    else if ((*iter)->getWidgetType() == "Editbox")
      return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<EditBox>(*iter);
    else if ((*iter)->getWidgetType() == "ButtonLabel")
      return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<ButtonLabel>(*iter);
    else if ((*iter)->getWidgetType() == "Menu")
      return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Menu>(*iter);
  }
}

auto type = SceneManager::getCurrentScene().m_gui.getType(widgetId);

SceneManager::getCurrentScene().m_gui.getWidget<decltype(type)>(widgetId)->attachToMenu(getId());
```

`Widget::Ptr` is just a `typedef std::shared_ptr<Widget>`. As you can see, `m_widgets` is a list filled with Widgets which are a base class that `Label`, `EditBox`, `ButtonLabel`, and Menu are derived from. I'm trying to cast downwards to those classes so I can get the type, and use my `getWidget()` to edit the derived object. I'm getting this error however:

> error: 'class std::shared_ptr' has no member named 'attachToMenu'|

This means obviously that it's not casting correctly and it's returning a Widget. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You have Undefined Behavior in the case where `iter == m_widgets.end()`. Might want to add `return nullptr` in that case.

Comment: What do you think `decltype(type)` is?

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, `decltype(type)` is a `std::shared_ptr<Widget>`, so `getWidget` returns a `std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>`, and calling `->attachToMenu(…)` on that is a no-no.

Comment: The downcast works fine. The return type of `getType` cause an upcast back to `Widget::Ptr`

Answer (score 1):

*"Widget::Ptr is just a typedef std::shared_ptr."*

I assume it is a typedef of `std::shared_ptr<Widget>`. If so, then the `dynamic_pointer_cast` casts down only within the function body, outside it's type is `std::shared_ptr<Widget>` (that's because the return type implies up-cast):

```
auto type = SceneManager::getCurrentScene().m_gui.getType(widgetId);
// type is std::shared_ptr<Widget>, that is, a pointer to base type
```

Additionally, using `getWidget<decltype(type)>` you actually expect the `getWidget<T>` to return `std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>`, which is far from what you want to achieve.

Eventually, downcasting usually indicates bad design. I believe you problem can be solved by making `attachToMenu` method virtual in `Widget` base class, then you do not need RTTI in runtime. Consider this:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    virtual ~Widget() = default;
    virtual void attachToMenu(const std::string& id) = 0;
};

class EditBox : public Widget
{
public:
    virtual void attachToMenu(const std::string& id) override
    {
        // do the stuff
    }
};

std::shared_ptr<Widget> widget = std::make_shared<EditBox>();
widget->attachToMenu(getId()); // calls EditBox::attachToMenu
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
auto type = ...
```

the type of `type` will be always `Widget::Ptr`, because this is the type returned by the function. All down casting happens within the function so does not matter. Then when you call `getWidget` with `decltype(type)` the static type is used, so again `Widget::Ptr`. You need to redesign.